# Make element stick to top when scrolled outside page

Tags: html, css

so I've got a `<div>` that I want to stick to the top when I've scrolled enough, instead of it going outside the window. How would I do this?

Comment: What have you tried thus far?  Please include your code.

Comment: I haven't really figured out what to try. I simply lack the proper understanding. Why else would i ask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **bootstrap affix** to get a sticky header on scroll. Check below snippet for reference.

Here `data-spy="affix"` used to identify affix container and `data-offset-top="150"` mentions the offset value that when to set stick on top.

```css
.bg-grey {
  background-color: grey;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
  </div>
  <div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="150">
    <h1 class="bg-grey">This is sticky content</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
    <p>Some content goes-here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer, Really deeply explained. Thanks for sharing!